# Show that 1+$\sqrt{3}$ is not a root of 1

Tags: abstract-algebra

Show that 1 + $\sqrt{3}$ is not a root of 1 in $\mathbb Z(\sqrt{3})$

Can anyone please check my proof:

1 + $\sqrt{3}$ has its minimal polynomial $x^2 - 2x - 2 \in \mathbb Z [x]$

Suppose it is a root of 1, then it is a root of the polynomial $x^n-1$ for some integer $n$. Then by the definition of minimal polynomial, $x^2 - 2x - 2$ must divide $x^n-1$. So we have a contradiction.

Is my proof correct?

Comment: $\Bbb{Z}(\sqrt{3})$ is not a field. Do you mean $\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{3})$?

Comment: Yes, you are right! I just edited the problem.

Answer (score 1):

One problem with your proof is that you haven't shown that $x^2-2x-2$ does not divide $x^n-1$. You've just stated that to be the case. It's certainly true that $x^2-2x-2$ does not divide $x^n-1$, but you should prove this.

Another way to show that $1+\sqrt{3}$ is not a root of unity is to think about absolute value. For any $z\in\Bbb{C}$, if $z$ is a root of unity, then we have that $z^n=1$ for some positive integer $n$. Taking absolute values, we have that $\vert z\vert^n=1$. Hence $\vert z\vert=1$. So if $z$ is a root of unity, then $\vert z\vert=1$. On the other hand, $\vert1+\sqrt{3}\vert=1+\sqrt{3}>1$, so $1+\sqrt{3}$ can't be a root of unity.

Comment: Thank you, here is my proof for "$x^2 - 2x - 2$ does not divide $x^n - 1$":  $x^n - 1 = (x - 1)(x^n-1 + ... + x +1)$. Since both factors are irreducible and not equal to $x^2 - 2x - 2$, so $x^2 - 2x - 2$ does not divide $x^n - 1$. Is this correct?

Comment: $x^{n-1} + x^{n-2} + \cdots + x + 1$ is not irreducible in general (only if $n$ is prime).

Comment: Another possible proof that $x^2 - 2x - 2$ does not divide $x^n - 1$ (other than reverting to the original problem and using absolute values): if $x^2 - 2x - 2$ did divide $x^n - 1$, say $x^n - 1 = q(x) (x^2 - 2x - 2)$, then $q(x)$ would have integer coefficients.  Now, if you reduce this equation mod 2, you get that this would imply that $x^2$ divides $x^n - 1$ in $\mathbb{F}_2[x]$.

Comment: The argument mdryizk gives is also salvageable but requires more advanced concepts: the irreducible factors of $x^n - 1$ are more generally the *cyclotomic polynomials* $\Phi_d(x)$ for $d \mid n$.  And then, since $\Phi_d(x)$ has degree $\varphi(d)$ where $\varphi$ is the Euler phi function, and this hits 2 only when $d = 3$ or $d = 6$, you just need to calculate $\Phi_3(x) = x^2 + x + 1$ and $\Phi_6(x) = x^2 - x - 1$ and observe neither is equal to $x^2 - 2x - 2$.

Comment: @DanielSchepler Thank you, I really appreciate the second proof. And I guess $\phi  _4$ also needs to be checked since it has degree 2.

Comment: Right, I just realized that myself - $\Phi_4(x) = x^2 + 1$.

Comment: Yet another argument that just popped into my mind: if $1 + \sqrt{3}$ were a root of 1, then its inverse $\frac{-1+\sqrt{3}}{2}$ would also have to be a root of 1 and therefore integral over $\mathbb{Z}$.  But it's not integral over $\mathbb{Z}$ since $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{3}]$ is integrally closed.

Comment: @DanielSchepler Your comments are excellent. Why not turn your comments into an answer to the original problem. I would be happy to upvote your answer.